# Is possible to set 'String' placeholder for versionCod` in android.defaultConfig?

Tags: android, gradle

I wonder if it is possible to set String placeholder for `versionCode` in `android.defaultConfig`.

We run a build machine that should replace all `<REPLACE>` places with original values but `versionCode` excepts integer only.

Something like:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 26
        minSdkVersion 14
        testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
        versionCode "<REPLACE_VERSION_CODE>"
        versionName "<REPLACE_VERSION_NMAE>"
```

Any ideas how to make it work?

So far I left `versionCode -99999` but I look for more gentle solution

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a variable in the gradle file and set it to some default value (e.g -99999) that can be replaced by your build machine.

For example

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    def version_code = -99999
    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 26
        minSdkVersion 14
        testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
        versionCode version_code
        versionName "<REPLACE_VERSION_NMAE>"
    }
}
```

This way you have a readable text (not int) on the versionCode line.